# Absolute element is behind sticky element and z-index does not work

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have :

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="button"></div>
      sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="body">body</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and the css:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;

  .sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100vh;

    .button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      translate: 10px 10px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: black;
      z-index: 10;
    }
  }

  .content {
    flex-grow: 1;

    .header {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      height: 56px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .body {
      height: 3000px;
    }
  }
}
```

I want the `.button` is over the header, but:

[image]

the `.button` is behind `.header`. I tried to chang `z-index` but it not working. Both `.sidebar` and `.header` is `position: sticky;`.

I also tried something to find the problem out but nothing.

If I create an `absolute` element in `.header`, everything good.

How I can fix this

Answer (score 1):

This must work

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;

  .sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index:2;

    .button {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      translate: 10px 10px;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      background-color: black;
      z-index: 10;
    }
  }

  .content {
    flex-grow: 1;

    .header {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      height: 56px;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    .body {
      height: 3000px;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="button"></div>
      sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">header</div>
      <div class="body">body</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will solve your issue...Just add z-index -1 in .header
class. I have mentioned in below code....hope it will work...let me know if not...Thank you...

```css
      .wrapper {
        display: flex;
      }
        .sidebar {
          width: 200px;
          position: sticky;
          top: 0;
          background-color: red;
          height: 100vh;
        }
          .button {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 0;
            translate: 10px 10px;
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: black;
            z-index: 10;
          }
        

        .content {
          flex-grow: 1;
        }
          .header {
            z-index: -1;
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            height: 56px;
            background-color: yellow;
          }

          .body {
            height: 3000px;
          }
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="sidebar">
        <div class="button"></div>
        sidebar
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="header">header</div>
        <div class="body">body</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: But the `.header` is behind the `.body`. The `.body` is a `static` element so it can be set index to behind the `.header`